# guice / hibernate - composite PK issues

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have 2 issues I can't seem to sort out:

1. Upon persisting an entity within a provider, the entity is stored in the database, but the attribute with @Version is not populated and hibernate thinks the entity is still transient when it isn't.  To "fix" this, I simply called entityManager.find and was able to get the entity as I expected (with an @Version and an active persistence context).
2. Other entities which depend on this entity a few layers down, are not being persisted and hibernate complains that one or more attributes in the PK are null, but when inspecting / debugging them, I see that they all have values and the .equals and .hashCode is implemented with all of the fields in the composite PK.

I am thinking these 2 issues are related, but they could be entirely separate.

EDIT #1: After debugging it more, I can see one of the values in the key class (the class mapped by @IdClass) is null, but the actual value is set in the entity.

EDIT #2: I traced the execution more and can see that hibernate is copying the entity, but it still has the PK fully intact at that point.  I haven't found where the Key class is being set, but that should lead me to the answer.

EDIT: #3: I see that somehow hibernate is not setting one of the values in the composite key.  This is happening somewhere when hibernate is copying the entity.